# php mysql sql fetch or insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I created a web portal but at last when I fetch paid and unpaid client in same MySQL table and I set value in MySQL for **paid client = '1' and unpaid client = '0'**.
Now, the problem is how can I fetch paid client on top and unpaid client after the paid client?

**Controller code**

```
public function alllist()
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('use_actual_code_msg'))
        {
            $user_servicetype=base64_decode($this->session->userdata('user_servicetype'));
            if ($this->input->get('submit_valid'))
            {
                if (empty($this->input->get('owner_name')) && empty($this->input->get('company_name')))
                {
                    echo "<script>alert('Please Enter Correct Name or Company Name'); window.location = 
                    'alllist'; </script>";
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('owner_name','Owner Name','trim');
                    $owner_name=$this->input->get('owner_name');
                    $company_name=$this->input->get('company_name');
                    $show_both_result=$this->wohp_model->show_by_column('ci_list_of_client',array(
                        'company_owner_name'=>$owner_name.' or',
                        'company_name'=>$company_name));
                    $show_name_result=$this->wohp_model->show_by_column('ci_list_of_client',array(
                        'company_owner_name'=>$owner_name));
                    $show_company_result=$this->wohp_model->show_by_column('ci_list_of_client',array(
                        'company_name'=>$company_name));
                    $this->load->view('list_of_hotels',array(
                        'view_show_both_result'=>$show_both_result,
                        'view_show_name_result'=>$show_name_result,
                        'view_show_company_result'=>$show_company_result));
                }
            }
            elseif ($this->input->get('input_star'))
            {
                $input_star=$this->input->get('input_star');
                $show_input_star=$this->wohp_model->show_by_column('ci_list_of_client',array(
                    'five_star_or_not'=>$input_star,'service_type_search'=>$user_servicetype));
                $this->load->view('list_of_hotels',array(
                    'view_input_star'=>$show_input_star));
            }
            else
            {
                $show_result=$this->wohp_model->show('ci_list_of_client');
                $this->load->view('list_of_hotels',array('view_show_result'=>$show_result));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>window.location = 'verification_code'; </script>";
        }
    }
```

**Model code**

```
public function show_by_column($tablname,$column)
    {
        $fetch_by_column_stmt=$this->db->get_where($tablname,$column);
        if ($fetch_by_column_stmt->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $fetch_by_column_stmt->result();
        }
        return array();
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: just put `order by field name of paid/unpaid client DESC` in your sql

Comment: Just a quesion or two...When can you be a paid and unpaid client at the same time? Are they not mutually exclusive? paid = 1 means Paid, paid=0 means Unpaid. And the code you are currently showing has nothing to do with your question that I can see.

Comment: sir I edit my question please see what change I do in sql query

Comment: update your code `$this->db->order_by("paid","DESC")`;

Comment: its create error **Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::num_rows()** <br> **Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::num_rows() in C:**

Comment: thanks sir problem solved after put order_by on upper side thanks for help sir